# Tweepy include_rts not working

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to retreive the statuses of the users without his retweets.

```
total_pages = 17
for page_count in range(1,total_pages+1):
    statuses = api.user_timeline(screen_name, count = 200, page = page_count, include_rts=False)
    for tweet in statuses:
        if tag.lower() in tweet.text.lower():
             print tweet.text
```

Unfortunately, its not sending all the tweets. I am trying to extract the tweets with a certain hashtag in my status but I don't find all the tweets that I posted (within the last 3200 limits)

if I leave include_rts = True, it returns all the tweets. but I don't want the my retweets too.

If there something wrong with Tweepy library ?

Comment: explain precisely what you want ? which RT's you want to keep and which you want to discard ?

Comment: i want to discard native retweets those that you generate by clicking on the retweet button of twitter

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy uses `'false'` or `0`, not `False`, and `true`, `t` or `1`, not `True`.

Comment: Python Booleans are supported as values for `include_rts` by Tweepy according to the first reply to https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1532

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Twitter API itself. In twitter API timeline requests, for example [user timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline), replies are removed *after* `count` tweets are selected.

> Using exclude_replies with the count parameter will mean you will
> receive up-to count tweets — this is because the count parameter
> retrieves that many Tweets before filtering out retweets and replies.

> The value of count is best thought of as a
> limit to the number of Tweets to return because suspended or deleted
> content is removed after the count has been applied. We include
> retweets in the count, even if include_rts is not supplied.

Also see [Twitter exclude_replies=true count=5 not returning 5 tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43415892/1921546)