# Twitter exclude_replies=true count=5 not returning 5 tweets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, twitter, backend

How do I return **specific** number of tweets **without** replies?

https://github.com/thujohn/twitter/issues/4

I found this answer on github but it is not helpful at all. Should make request to API in a while loop until i get 5 tweets? Really?

Thank you for your help.

These are my params:

  `const params = {
    lang: 'en',
    count: 5, // I want exactly 5 tweets
    user_id: 12312312,
    screen_name: 'somescreenname',
    tweet_mode: 'extended', // I need media
    exclude_replies: true, // I DO NOT want replies
    include_rts: 1, // I want retweets from the user
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In twitter API timeline requests, for example [user timeline](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline), replies are removed after `count` tweets are selected.

> Using exclude_replies with the count parameter will mean you will
> receive up-to count tweets — this is because the count parameter
> retrieves that many Tweets before filtering out retweets and replies.

I would suggest you to use a larger `count` (upto 200 is allowed) and select first five tweets from the response.

Comment: That has to be the worst API ever made.